# I am looking for electromagnetism textbooks which start from special relativity

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, resource-recommendations, education

I have studied Griffiths' book and am looking for another textbook to review/deepen my understanding of electrodynamics. I happened to read Susskind's 'Special Relativity and Classical Field Theory' and got really impressed. I am wondering is there any textbook for physics majors which motivates electromagnetism from special relativity?

Comment: There is an extensive book recommendation in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/
You might want to check it out

Comment: You might care to read reviews of Purcell and Morin's book: Electricity and Magnetism.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation!

Comment: Classical Electrodynamics by Ohanian and Principles of electrodynamics by Schwartz derive Maxwells equations just from SR and Coloumb's law

Answer (score 3):

The first book that comes to mind with an approach starting from special relativity is the second volume of the series by Landau and Lifshitz titled [The Classical Theory of Fields](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/The_Classical_Theory_of_Fields.html?id=X18PF4oKyrUC&redir_esc=y).

However, there exist more modern presentations of the subject which I believe would be a better primary reference for a second course in electromagnetic theory, which also serve as a decent starting point for further generalities in areas such as quantum field theory and general relativity. One such book that comes to mind is Scheck's [Classical Field Theory](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Classical_Field_Theory.html?id=IZBQDwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y), which is a follow-up to his previous book titled [Mechanics](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/_/2GoLtAEACAAJ?hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0_bGtnob8AhXsR2wGHbnrAzgQ7_IDegQIEBAF) which introduces the appropriate mathematical machinery and also special relativity.

Another rather illuminating albeit relatively short introduction to the subject in this manner can be found in Part 2 of the magnum opus by Misner, Wheeler and Thorne titled [Gravitation](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Gravitation.html?id=w4Gigq3tY1kC&redir_esc=y).

Lastly, if you're interested in a more axiomatic exposition which naturally follows the same approach, you can have a look at Hehl and Obukhov's [Foundations of Classical Electrodynamics](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Foundations_of_Classical_Electrodynamics/48-hHXL-CYUC?hl=en&gbpv=0).

Hope you find these references useful :)

Comment: I have never heard of Scheck's book. Thank you for the recommendation!